# Confused, with activerecord, how to I get all items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
users = User.find()
```

[This page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) doesn't seem to tell me how to do this?

I'm sure I am missing something here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`User.find(:all)`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000333) or its alias [`User.all()`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000336).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do something for each user, use find_each:

```
User.find_each do |user|
    # Do something with "user"
end
```

This will be much more efficient than fetching all of the objects, since it will fetch in batches from the DB instead of grabbing everything at once and stuffing it all in memory somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Users.find(:all)
```

that should do the trick.